# ListAdapter does not update indices (positions) of the items in the RecyclerView after deleting an item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a simple `RecyclerView` that holds items that have their own `PopupMenu`s. You can delete an item using that menu.

Now before showing You the code, take a look at the problem (please refer to the screenshots as well):

- First, I delete an item on some intermediary position (in my case - position 1 or *index 1*),
- Then, when trying to access the `PopupMenu` of the last item - the one at the position 1 at the second screenshot, **the application crashes**,
- It appears as though the **actual position** of that item was **not 1 but 2**, so the *indices* of the items in the `RecyclerView` were *not updated*:

```
Process: com.sweak.teachernotebook, PID: 15271
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at androidx.core.view.ViewGroupKt.get(ViewGroup.kt:32)
        at com.sweak.teachernotebook.ui.main.fragment.NoteFragment.showOptionsMenu(NoteFragment.kt:78)
        ...
```

[image: Deleting an entry]
[image: Trying to open PopupMenu on an item of position that is out of range]

Here is the most relevant code:

**NoteFragment.kt**

```kotlin
class NoteFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        // Getting the reference to the AndroidViewModel
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
            NoteViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application))
            .get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        ...
        // Getting the reference to the RecyclerView
        noteRecyclerView = binding.recyclerViewNotes
        
        // Creating the ListAdapter for the RecyclerView
        noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(object : NoteAdapter.OptionsMenuClickListener {
            override fun onOptionsMenuClicked(position: Int) {
                // Implementation of the showOptionsMenu method below
                showOptionsMenu(position)
            }
        })
        noteRecyclerView.adapter = noteAdapter

        // Setting the observer for the ViewModel data
        noteViewModel.allNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { notes ->
            noteAdapter.submitList(notes)
        })

        ...
    }

    private fun showOptionsMenu(position: Int) {
        // Here upon trying to get the view at the position greater than the list size, the IndexOutOfBoundException occurs
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, noteRecyclerView[position].findViewById(R.id.note_options))
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.note_options_menu)

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
            override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
                when (item?.itemId) {
                    R.id.delete -> {
                        // Here the deletion of an item happens
                        noteViewModel.delete(noteAdapter.getNoteAt(position))
                        return true
                    }
                    R.id.edit -> {
                        // Editing the note...
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })

        popupMenu.show()
    }
}
```

**NoteAdapter.kt**

```kotlin
class NoteAdapter(
    private var optionsMenuClickListener: OptionsMenuClickListener
) : ListAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {
    
    class NoteHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var noteTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title)
        var noteDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_description)
        var noteOptions: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_options)
    }

    interface OptionsMenuClickListener {
        fun onOptionsMenuClicked(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
        ...
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote: Note = getItem(position)
        holder.noteTitle.text = currentNote.title
        holder.noteDescription.text = currentNote.description

        // What happens upon clicking the menu button on a single item
        holder.noteOptions.setOnClickListener {
            // The action specified in the implementation of the OptionsMenuClickListener is executed
            // with the parameter @position provided while binding the NoteHolder with the item on the specified position
            optionsMenuClickListener.onOptionsMenuClicked(position)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        // Callback for the ListAdapter to evaluate the differences between the items
        private val DIFF_CALLBACK: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note> =
            object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note>() {
                override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
                }
                override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Note, newItem: Note): Boolean {
                    return (oldItem.title == newItem.title) and
                            (oldItem.description == newItem.description)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**NoteViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class NoteViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    
    // We get the reference to the data that we are working on (allNotes)
    // to observe it (since it is LiveData) in the NoteFragment.kt
    private val repository: NoteRepository = NoteRepository(application)
    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>> = repository.allNotes

    ...

    fun delete(note: Note) {
        repository.delete(note)
    }
}
```

I've tried to reload the dataset after deleting an item using `noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it didn't work.

Since then I couldn't come up with any solution to this problem.

I would appreciate any help!

**Edit:** Another kind of question I could ask in this situation would be on how to refresh the `NoteAdapter` so the indices of the items are reset to normal (e.g. 0, 1, 2 instead of 0, 1, 3). Maybe now someone will have an answer.

Comment: After repository.delete(); call get all notes and set to Mutable live data .so observer will set new updated note.

Comment: Can You post the example code?

Comment: Does `noteAdapter.submitList(notes)` get triggered when you delete an item?

Comment: @Zain Yes, it does get triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `onBindViewHolder` method of the **NoteAdapter**.

The change that resolves the issue is changing the usage of the parameter `position` to `holder.absoluteAdapterPosition` because according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()):

> Sometimes, you may need to get the exact adapter position to do some actions in response to user events. In that case, you should use this method which will calculate the Adapter position of the ViewHolder.

The modified and correct code from the question now looks like this:

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentNote: Note = getItem(holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
        holder.noteTitle.text = currentNote.title
        holder.noteDescription.text = currentNote.description

        holder.noteOptions.setOnClickListener {
            optionsMenuClickListener.onOptionsMenuClicked(holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using LiveData,change liveData to MutableLiveData,so that we can Update value for liveData in your repository.(allNotes in Repository class)

```
MutableLiveData<List<Note>> allNotes=new MutableLiveData();
```

Within your delete function set new value to allNotes after deletion.

```
 delete(Note note){
    //Here your deletion code
    //again call getAllNotes() from  database.this method should return List<Note>
     allNotes.setValue(getAllNotes()).
 
}
```

Make viewmodel.allNotes as MutableLiveData and should return repository.allNotes.Then it will emit updated value from repository to Observer.

Comment: I'm using a Room database and it does not support `MutableLiveData`, so I can't use this solution.

Comment: No.Room and MutableLiveData are different thing in Architecture component. you are using LiveData ,so you can definitely use MutableLiveData.share your DAO.@sweak.

Comment: atDao
interface NoteDao {

    ...

    atDelete
    fun delete(note: Note)

    ...

    atQuery("SELECT * FROM notes")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Note>>
}